# Django testing form.is_valid()

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-testing

My view have optional parameter in url. I pass this parameter (`<int:jobNr>`/`None`)to form in `get_form_kwargs`

```
class AddHoursView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):

    form_class = AddHoursForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        # pass "jobNr" keyword argument from current url to form
        kwargs = super(AddHoursView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs[JOB_PARAM] = self.kwargs.get(JOB_PARAM)
        return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit = False)

        # If url/jobNR take jobNr from URL, if not take from form
        try:
            jobNr = self.kwargs[JOB_PARAM]
        except KeyError:
            jobNr = form.cleaned_data[JOB_WORKER].jobNr

        job = models.Job.objects.get(jobNr = jobNr)

        jobWorker = models.JobWorker.objects.get_or_create(job = job,
                                                user = self.request.user)
        self.object.jobWorker = jobWorker[0]
        self.object.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('worktime:myjobs'))
```

In form `__init__` If url `/foo/jobNr/` create `self.jobNr` with url parameter. If url `/foo/`  create new field.

```
class AddHoursForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):   
        #Add jobworker field to from Worktime model if any jobNr pass in url
        #When in url will be parameter. Job foreignkey will be set by automat.
        self.jobNr = kwargs.pop(JOB_PARAM, None)
        super(AddHoursForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if not self.jobNr:
            self.fields[JOB_WORKER] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Job.objects.all())

    def clean(self):

        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        date = cleaned_data.get('date')

        if self.jobNr:
            jobDate = Job.objects.get(jobNr=self.jobNr).start

        elif not cleaned_data.get(JOB_WORKER).start: 
            raise forms.ValidationError("Dat work don't start yet")

        else:
            jobDate = cleaned_data.get(JOB_WORKER).start

        if date<jobDate:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Wrong date")

        return cleaned_data
```

And now i want to code tests for a form. This is what i tried

```
    def test_no_jobNr_in_url_and_no_date(self):

        job = Job.objects.create(jobNr = 1, street = 'a', city = 'a',
                            zip = 'a')

        form_data = {'description': 'description', 'hours': 20}
        form = AddHoursForm(form_data)
        # Override field jobWorker after __init__ form
        form.fields['jobWorker'] = job


        self.assertFalse(form.is_valid())
```

And this is what i get `AttributeError: 'Job' object has no attribute 'disabled'` After 5h i need help. I have no idea anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't assign `job` to a form field (that's what `form.fields['jobWorker']` is). If you want to assign an initial value, you should do:

```
form.fields['jobWorker'].initial = job
```

But I think you want to pass `job` as the chosen model, you should just do that in data:

```
form_data = {'description': 'description', 'hours': 20, 'jobWorker': job.pk}
form = AddHoursForm(form_data)
self.assertFalse(form.is_valid)
```